# Blocking promises angular

Tags: angularjs

My current implementation is this:

```
getGroupMembersIDsWithID(groupIDs[i]).then(function(memberIDs) {
    for (var i in memberIDs) {
        [1]
        getMemberFirstNameWithID(memberIDs[i]).then(function(firstName) {
            [2]
            getMemberLastNameWithID(memberIDs[i]).then(function(lastName) {
                group.members.push({
                    id: memberIDs[i],
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName
                });
            });
        });
        [3]
    }
});
```

When debugging, the order of calls goes:

> [1], [3], [1], [3], [2], [2]

This creates a problem in this system as, for example, in the `for` loop, the `lastName` of `i` will actually be set to the `lastName` of `i + 1`.
I've implemented promises and thought it would have worked but obviously not:

```
var getMemberFirstNameWithID = function(memberID) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + memberID);

    userRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        deferred.resolve(snapshot.val().firstName);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I need the order of the calls to be:

> [1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]

So, what is the best way to halt the execution until a promise is called back. Basically, so the promise is blocking.
If that's not the prefered method of doing it *(as I've seen people say that you shouldn't block a promise)*, what would the preferred method be?

Comment: You can't make asynchronous code blocking. But your problem is a closure problem, not an asynchronism problem. Use `memberIDs;forEach(function(memberId) { ... })` to loop.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet! Post this as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, so the promise is blocking.

This fundamentally shouldn't be done. It's not how promises/javascript work. There are ways to block JS (promises or not) but really, this isn't in the spirit of JavaScript.

Your best course of action is to package your [3] in a function (I like to use a variable for this):

```
var three = function() { [3]; }
```

Then, at the appropriate time (perhaps a last `.then(...)`) call function `three`.

Taking your example:

```
getGroupMembersIDsWithID(groupIDs[i]).then(function(memberIDs) {
    for (var i in memberIDs) {
        [1]
        var three = function() { [3]; }
        getMemberFirstNameWithID(memberIDs[i]).then(function(firstName) {
            [2]
            getMemberLastNameWithID(memberIDs[i]).then(function(lastName) {
                group.members.push({
                    id: memberIDs[i],
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName
                });
            });
        }).then(three); //I think this would be the appropriate spot

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises can be worked with. You can combine multiple promises using `$q.all`. Whenever you have a promise return it, so caller functions can wait for the callee function's promises. And don't forget error handling - on every level (when using a `.then`). This way, they won't get swallowed somewhere down the line. Unless, of course you can do meaningful error handling at some point.

I took the liberty to really change your code, so you can see what's possible. The big plus here is that you can send the first and last name requests (I suppose they are requests to a server) at the same time and don't have to wait for the response of the first name until you can start the request of the last name.

```
return getGroupMembersIDsWithID(groupIDs[i]).then(function(memberIDs) {
  var promises = [],
      memberPromises = [];

  angular.forEach(memberIDs, function(memberId) {
    //[1]
    memberPromises = [];
    memberPromises.push(getMemberFirstNameWithID(memberId));
    memberPromises.push(getMemberLastNameWithID(memberId));

    promises.push($q.all(memberPromises).then(function(responses) {
      //kind of [2], although resolved only when first AND last name are done
      return $q.resolve(group.members.push({
        id: memberId,
        firstName: responses[0],
        lastName: responses[1]
      }));
      //kind of [3], would have to return later then though
    }, function(error) {
      return $q.reject(error);
    })
  });

  return $q.all(promises);
}, function(error) {
  return $q.reject(error);
});
```

*Not tested, though*